# Can a converted array be compared to another converted array?

Tags: java, arrays

Ok I was trying to word the question right so that I get the help I need. What I got is a simple purse/coin program that compares String arrays to another String array. Forgive the long drawn out loops/nested loops/logic because in this assignment I can't use the methods from java array and collections class.
This is a class assignment so please explain the process and not just answer.

(Theory): I was thinking that my comparison of the 2 converted arrays is the cause of the problem, but I couldn't figure out a way to compare each element in the array list to each element in the other array list.

Purse.class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A purse holds a collection of coins.
 */
public class Purse
{
    private ArrayList<String> coins;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty purse.
     */
    public Purse()
    {
        coins = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * Add a coin to the purse.
     * 
     * @param coinName
     *            the coin to add
     */
    public void addCoin(String coinName)
    {
        coins.add(coinName);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string describing the object.
     * 
     * @return a string in the format "Purse[coinName1,coinName2,...]"
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String coinName1 = "Quarter";
        String coinName2 = "Dime";
        String coinName3 = "Nickel";
        String coinName4 = "Penny";

        String str = "Actual:"
                + "Purse["
                + (coinName1 + "," + coinName2 + "," + coinName3 + "," + coinName2)
                + "]";

        return str;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if a purse has the same coins in the same or different order
     * as another purse.
     * 
     * @param other
     *            the other purse
     * @return true if the two purses have the same coins in the same or
     *         different order, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean sameCoins(Purse other)
    {
        if (this.coins.size() != other.coins.size())
        {
            System.out.println("1");
            return false;
        }


        int matched = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.coins.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < other.coins.size(); j++)
            {
                if (this.coins.toArray() == other.coins.toArray())
                {
                    matched++;
                    System.out.println("2");
                    System.out.println(this.coins.toArray());
                    System.out.println(other.coins.toArray());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return matched == this.coins.size();

    }

}
```

PurseTester.class:

```
/**
 * This class tests the Purse class.
 */
public class PurseTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Purse p = new Purse();
        p.addCoin("Quarter");
        p.addCoin("Dime");
        p.addCoin("Nickel");
        p.addCoin("Dime");

        System.out.println(p.toString());
        System.out.println("Expected: Purse[Quarter,Dime,Nickel,Dime]");

        Purse a = new Purse();
        a.addCoin("Quarter");
        a.addCoin("Dime");
        a.addCoin("Nickel");
        a.addCoin("Dime");

        Purse b = new Purse();
        b.addCoin("Nickel");
        b.addCoin("Dime");
        b.addCoin("Dime");
        b.addCoin("Quarter");

        System.out.println(a.sameCoins(b));
        System.out.println("Expected: true");

        Purse c = new Purse();
        c.addCoin("Quarter");
        c.addCoin("Penny");
        c.addCoin("Nickel");
        c.addCoin("Dime");

        Purse d = new Purse();
        d.addCoin("Nickel");
        d.addCoin("Dime");
        d.addCoin("Dime");
        d.addCoin("Quarter");

        System.out.println(c.sameCoins(d));
        System.out.println("Expected: false");

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Actual:Purse[Quarter,Dime,Nickel,Dime]
Expected: Purse[Quarter,Dime,Nickel,Dime]
false
Expected: true
false
Expected: false
```

Expected output:

```
Actual:Purse[Quarter,Dime,Nickel,Dime]
Expected: Purse[Quarter,Dime,Nickel,Dime]
true
Expected: true
false
Expected: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loops never look in the `List`s, you just repeatedly check `==` on two arrays. You need to compare the elements, like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this.coins.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!this.coins.get(i).equals(other.coins.get(i)))
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
```

This, however, compares assuming you want the same order. If you need to compare ignoring order you need to loop over the other array and remove the element if you find it, otherwise `return false`.

```
    final List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(other.coins);
    outerLoop:
    for (final String mine : coins)
    {
        final Iterator<String> otherIter = copy.iterator();
        while (otherIter.hasNext())
        {
            if (mine.equals(otherIter.next()))
            {
                otherIter.remove();
                continue outerLoop;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This method is obviously hugely inefficient, if you sorted the `List`s first then used the first method that would be optimal. But given that you cannot use `Array` methods I assume you cannot use a `TreeSet` or `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: The iterator method **without** the `remove` is basically the same as (what I believe) OP was **trying to do** with the double-for-loop. It's worth noting that this (without the `remove`) may classify 2 arrays as equal when there's 2 of the same item in the 1st array and only 1 of that item in the 2nd, since both will match to the one item.

Comment: Yes, this works. I'm just pointing out that what I think OP may have been trying to do won't work, that this is similar to that and that this doesn't have that problem because of `remove`. Maybe someone will find that useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.coins.toArray() == other.coins.toArray()
```

This code always returns `false` because it doesn’t compare the content of the two arrays, it tests whether the two expressions references the same array (i.e. modifying one will modify the other).

Basically, you need to count the number of each kind of coins in each list, and then compare the result. If the possible kinds of coin is know in advance, it is easy: just have two variables for each kind of coins (one for this purse, and one for the other purse). If the possible kinks of coin is not known, you’ll have to use a `Map`.

Comment: "are the same" is a bit unclear, "reference / points to the exact same object (mainly achieved by actually setting them equal to each other at some point with the `=`-operator)" would be better.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is I have to take the string values and set them equal to a numeric value. Then have each array's total compared to the other array's total?

Comment: Not at all. I mean looking at one array, counting the number of quarters it contains, then looking at the other array, counting the number of quarters it contains, then compare the two results. If they are not the same, you return `false`, if they are, you go on for the next kind of coin.

Comment: Oh thats a different way of thinking about it.